# How To Put 2 PHP Variables On Url Without Using '&'

Tags: php, html

Let me explain with an example:

I have this link (php file): http:// mywebsite.com/abc/?id=fasfsa&id2=derp

On the Php I have the 2 variables id and id2.

So I'm using another php file to post the link but he has other variables and it doesn't consider mine.

Let me show how:

http: //website.com/publish.php?url=**http: //mywebsite.com/abc/?id=fasfsa&id2=derp**&linkname=**blabla**&image=**http: //google.com/g.jpg**

This is the sintax of publish.php. I can't edit that file. when I publish my link it shows only **http:// mywebsite.com/abc/?id=fasfsa**

It doesn't show the variable 'id2'. Anyone knows a method?

It doesnt show the variable id2 because it takes only his variables (url,linkname,image). I want to put all the link on the variable url .

Comment: `urlencode()` whatever is data.

Comment: what do you mean? where should I put it?

Comment: Oh thanks, searched on google. I went on https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/ and put my url and now it seems to work!

Comment: You don't need the `tools4noobs`, use the PHP function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php, in your code.

Comment: Another method is .htaccess RewriteRule. search on google ;)